# Is wifi available on the Amtrak Southwest Chief?

Tags: trains, wifi, amtrak

Is wifi available if I get the cheapest ticket on the "4 Southwest Chief" train?

I looked at https://www.amtrak.com/services/contentService.iblegacy.routes.southwest-chief.html
couldn't find any info

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Currently wifi is not available on Amtrak Southwest Cheif.

Elsewhere on the Amtrak website you can find this list which shows the most upto date list of the trains that have available Wifi.

https://www.amtrak.com/onboard/journey-with-wi-fi-train-station.html?content=

Having used the Wifi system on several routes it is worth noting that service can be slow/sporadic

Comment: Capacity is low, and streaming sites like Netflix are _blocked_.

Comment: Also note that many Amtrak routes (especially in the Western U.S.A.) are not within 4G/3G coverage for long distances, in case you are thinking of tethering to your phone.